# R - mocking API requests with `gh` package

Tags: r, unit-testing, github, mocking, testthat

I am trying to mock the output of a `gh` API request:

```
httptest2::with_mock_dir("gh", {
  test_that("api works", {
    gh::gh("GET /repos/r-lib/gh")
  })
})
```

I am trying to set up testing for custom functions that routinely make API calls to GitHub and I am using `gh` to make these requests. I am following this tutorial as guidance: https://books.ropensci.org/http-testing/

However, no directory is created when this function is run. Is there anyway to capture the output of `gh::gh` and store it as a mock API return so that I can run my tests without needing GitHub authentication or even an internet connection?

Answer (score 2):

`httptest2` is [specifically designed to test `httr2` requests](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httptest2/index.html):

> This package helps with writing tests for packages that use `httr2`

Unfortunately, [`gh` uses `httr`](https://github.com/r-lib/gh/blob/main/DESCRIPTION):

```
Imports:
    cli (>= 3.0.1),
    gitcreds,
    httr (>= 1.2),
    ini,
    jsonlite
```

This means that you can't directly use `httptest2` with `gh`.

However, using `gh` [source code](https://github.com/r-lib/gh/blob/main/R/gh.R), you can extract the parameters of the `GET`  request sent to `httr` by `gh`:

```
gh_get <- function(endpoint, ..., per_page = NULL, .token = NULL, .destfile = NULL,
               .overwrite = FALSE, .api_url = NULL, .method = "GET",
               .limit = NULL, .accept = "application/vnd.github.v3+json",
               .send_headers = NULL, .progress = TRUE, .params = list()) {
  params <- c(list(...), .params)
  params <- gh:::drop_named_nulls(params)
  
  if (is.null(per_page)) {
    if (!is.null(.limit)) {
      per_page <- max(min(.limit, 100), 1)
    }
  }
  
  if (!is.null(per_page)) {
    params <- c(params, list(per_page = per_page))
  }
  
  req <- gh:::gh_build_request(
    endpoint = endpoint, params = params,
    token = .token, destfile = .destfile,
    overwrite = .overwrite, accept = .accept,
    send_headers = .send_headers,
    api_url = .api_url, method = .method
  )
  req
}

req <- gh_get("GET /repos/r-lib/gh")
req

#$method
#[1] "GET"

#$url
#[1] "https://api.github.com/repos/r-lib/gh"

#$headers
#                      User-Agent                           Accept 
#   "https://github.com/r-lib/gh" "application/vnd.github.v3+json" 

#$query
#NULL

#$body
#NULL

#$dest
#<request>
#Output: write_memory
```

This allows with the example you provided to use `httr2` to send the same request :

```
library(httr2)
resp_httr2 <- request(base_url=req$url) %>%
              req_perform() %>%
              resp_body_json()
```

If you are mainly interested in `json` content, the results are the same, only the attributes differ :

```
resp_gh <- gh::gh("GET /repos/r-lib/gh")

all.equal(resp_gh,resp_httr2,check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

If you want to use `httptest2`, switching to `httr2` would work:

```
with_mock_dir("gh", {
   test_that("api works", {
   resp <- request(base_url=req$url) %>%
     req_perform() %>%
     resp_body_json()
     expect_equal(resp$full_name,"r-lib/gh")})
 })
#Test passed 
#[1] TRUE
```

Offline testing now works because `gh\api.github.com` directory was created by `httptest2`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take inspiration from [`tests/testthat/test-mock-repos.R`](https://github.com/r-lib/gh/blob/ae5e0ea401f623596ac20979570aab903e132130/tests/testthat/test-mock-repos.R)

```
res <- gh(
    TMPL("/repos/{owner}/{repo}"),
    owner = "gh-testing",
    repo = test_repo,
    .token = tt()
  )
  expect_equal(res$name, test_repo)
  expect_equal(res$description, "Test repo for gh")
  expect_equal(res$homepage, "https://github.com/r-lib/gh")
  expect_false(res$private)
  expect_false(res$has_issues)
  expect_false(res$has_wiki)
```

A `GET` method would not create any directory.